# Automatic Reclustering & Search optimization

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake,
'show tables like ' command is not showing 'automatic clustering on' column. i have added a clustering key to the table & now, i am trying to add search optimization and command is getting rejected saying that the automatic clustering is not on.  has anything changed in snowflake recently, which is not available in documentation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search optimization is in public preview and may require support double check to see if your account is enabled with the right parameters etc.  Please open a support case to get the follow-up.  Thank you.

Seeling

Answer (score 0):

Even though Search Optimization is in public preview but the Search Optimization service has to be enabled at the account level along with Automatic Clustering services before it can be used.

If you are issuing below command

```
alter table <table_name> add search optimization;
```

and getting error like "Search Optimization requires Automatic Clustering to be enabled" then please get in touch with Snowflake Support.

Please note that for Search Optimization service to be enabled for Snowflake account, it has to be Enterprise Edition and above.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions.html#sql-support
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service.html